# Checking toggle button state and background image

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I'm attemping to check if a toggle button isChecked() and if its background equals a specific drawable.  I've been trying to get this for over 2hrs and the solution eludes me.

The toggle button has an xml set to it with the images its supposed to set when the state of the button is changed

This is what I've attemped so far

```
tbTest1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (tbTest1.isChecked())
                {
                    if(tbTest1.getBackground().equals("testimg.png")) {
                        Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Test Image Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //fileNames.add("testimg.png");
                    //isChecked--;
                    Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Test Image Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

This gives no results

I've also tried this

```
tbTest1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (tbTest1.isChecked() && tbTest1.getBackground().equals(R.drawable.testimg))
                {
                        Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Test Image Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Test Image Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

This skips straight to the ELSE statement

Here is the xml for testimg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/testimg1"
    android:state_checked="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/testimg2"
    android:state_checked="true"/>

</selector>
```

When the activity loads, the TB state is off and the image is set to testimg1.  When a user presses the TB, the state changes to on and the image changes to testimg2 and will Toast a message that it was added(to an ArrayList thats being added later).  When the user presses it again, there should be a Toast that says it was removed(from said ArrayList)

Comment: getBackground() returns a drawable object.  I'm not sure how it translates to a string, but I'd assume it would not produce the name.

Comment: R.drawable.testing is a number (int) that has been assigned to the given drawable resource, it is not a Drawable object.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this.

Updated Answer:

**INSIDE ACTIVITY A**

```
tbTest1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (tbTest1.isChecked()){
                //Button is checked, add image String name into ArrayList<String> mArray;                   

                }
                else
                {
                 //Button is not checked, remove the image String name from ArrayList<String> mArray;
                }
            }
        });
```

After you have populated the `ArrayList<String> mArray`, you will probably have some button that will move you to Activity B.

Create a Bundle and store the `ArrayList<String> mArray;`

```
    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
    mBundle.putStringArrayList("ARRAYLIST", mArray);
```

Sending the data to Activity B

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, ACTIVITY_B.class);
intent.putExtra("BUNDLE", mBundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

**INSIDE ACTIVITY B**

```
ArrayList<String> mArray = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (extras != null) {
   Bundle mBundle = extras.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
   if (mBundle != null) {
        // do stuff
        //pull the ArrayList out of the Bundle and create a new ArrayList<String>

        mArray = mBundle.getStringArrayList("ARRAYLIST")   ; 

        // You now have the ArrayList<String> from Activity A, you can create and if statement, or some type of logic to handle generating pictures based on the String Names.


   }        
}
```

UPDATE 2:

**INSIDE ACTIVITY B**

You should be able to access the Drawable this way, you would

```
tbTest1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (tbTest1.isChecked(){
                        Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Test Image Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Drawable currentDrawable = tbTest1.getBackground();
                        //set currentDrawable to the background of a temporary image view

                         mImageView.setBackground(currentDrawable);

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Test Image Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Does it matter that the xml sets the background of the toggle button to two different images depending on the state of the button?

Comment: See if this solution works, also post the XML. What are you looking to do anyways with this code you are implementing? There may be a better way to do it all around.

Comment: Well you could potentially call setBackground() and manually set the background image within onClick() if you really wanted to. I take it that my solution did not work?

Comment: Original solution failed as well

Comment: So are you trying to add the image to an ArrayList? or are you looking to Add/Remove an item that the toggle button is associated with? I am just trying to figure out what you are trying to verify the background resource for, especially if you know what it will be due to the selector. I updated the answer to provide some insight as to how I am thinking.

Comment: Basically in Activity A, a user selects 4 images from a selection of 8 images.  Each of the 8 images in Activity A has a set of 4 images that are associated(on paper lol) with each. So when the user selects the 4 images on Activity A, the 4 Toggle Buttons on Activity B populate with the images associated with the image the user selected on Activity A.  In Activity B the user selects 2 of the 4 images. I want those 2 image names to be saved to the ArrayList.

Comment: You anticipate all these images will have pre-set associations? or are the images selected on Activity A randomly assigned 4 child images?

Comment: I'm sorry yes I know what the images are that are associated with each on activity A

Comment: I updated the answer, this should help you with communicating the image names selected in Activity A to Activity B, you will have to implement logic to handle the images in Activity B.

Comment: Im sorry i think im confusing you a little.  Let me see if can make what i need clearer.  In Activity A, a user selects 4 images from a group of 8.  Now depending on which 4 images were chosen, Activity B's 4 toggle buttons will populate with the proper images.  This part works.  Whats causing an issue is determining when a toggle button on Activity B is pressed, what image was there.  Does that help?

Comment: If you were to use the the UPDATE 2 part of my answer, can you try testing what Drawable is created in isChecked(), and set this drawable to an ImageView? This may help in finding out whether or not the Drawable is an individual image drawable, or if it is the selector drawable. You ,may also want to add the android:clickable="true" to the ImageView inside the Activity B xml layout.